# Size issue with embedding layer in Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, kaggle

**Problem:**
The Keras embedding layers I've defined appear to be the incorrect size, as suggested by the error I'm getting.

```
InvalidArgumentError: indices[19,0] = 99 is not in [0, 31)
```

**Code:**
Kaggle notebook - https://www.kaggle.com/benseto/tf-ffnnregressor
Not sure if you need an account to access the code. If so, I'll look at exporting this outside.

**Summary of Problem:**

I'm using the old "Bluebook for Bulldozers" Kaggle competition for learning. I'm attempting to train a feed-forward neural network for this regression exercise (price prediction). Because the categorical features have many unique features, the strategy I'm taking is to train a Keras embedding layer for each of these categorical features, rather than one-hot encoding (which blows dataframe to an unwieldy size).

I've managed to almost get this working, but believe there's an error in the size of the embedding layers:

Error during fit():

```
InvalidArgumentError: indices[19,0] = 99 is not in [0, 31)
```

Through searching stackoverflow, people have concluded this is due to an incorrect size for the Embedding layer, typically the input dimension needs to be vocab_size + 1.

To generate a separate Keras embedding layer for each categorical feature, cell #25 of the linked notebook defines each embedding layer:

```
# Build layer to ingest each categorical features vector
def build_embedding_layer(num_categories, inputs, concats, name = 'categorical'):
    categories = num_categories + 1             # Per Keras docs, embedding input dim should be input_size + 1
    dimensions = min(50, categories // 2 + 1)

    input = keras.layers.Input(shape = (1,), name = name)
    embedding = keras.layers.Embedding(categories, dimensions, input_length = 1)(input)
    embedding = keras.layers.Reshape(target_shape = (dimensions,))(embedding)

    inputs.append(input)
    concats.append(embedding)
```

In the above function, num_categories is the number of unique records for each feature vector, while inputs and concats represent arrays holding the final input tensors for each feature.

**What have I tried:**
I've tried to manually increase the size of the embeddings layer to a large number but still run into the stated issue when calling fit().

At this point, I'm stuck and any suggestions and/or insights into this issue is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As a follow-up, I've lifted this code into a different environment (Google Colab) and it's working there. Therefore, there must be a bug in the original runtime environment (Kaggle) and nothing wrong with the code itself.